# Add Link to a cell in Table antd

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to make the cell of the antd table behave as a link so that it can show all the features that a context menu of a link shows like Open in a new tab and all. I made the cell clickable by implementing onClick method under onCell props. But it doesn't give the feature of Open in a new tab and all. So how can I achieve this?

This is how onCell props look like currently:

```
 onCell: record => ({
     onClick: (event) => {
             if(event.ctrlKey) {
                     this.linkViewerNewTab(record.id);
             } else {
                     this.linkViewer(record.id);
             }
     },
 }),
```

Comment: I implemented the redirection in antd table , like this :

<Button><Link to={'./newPage?id='+id} target={"_blank"} >Test Button</Link></Button>
igave it inside the render option.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to render the cells with a `Link` and it will take care of the rest itself

```
<Link to={url} >Cell Data</Link>
```

Edit - This would add make just the content clickable, if you want whole cell to be clickable, you can tweak the css a bit

```
.ant-table-tbody>tr>td {
  padding: 0;
}

.ant-table-tbody>tr>td>a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 16px;
}
```

But if you want to do it the way you're doing, you can do like this

```
 onCell: record => ({
     onClick: (event) => {
             const url = '';
             if(event.ctrlKey) {
                     const win = window.open(url, '_blank');
                     win.focus();
             } else {
                     this.props.history.push(url); // Assuming you're using react router
             }
     },
 }),
```

Comment: Thanks Siddharth for your reply. Actually adding link to the cell content adds link around the content only and not the whole cell of the table and onClick method in my code is working fine but it is not giving me an option to Open in a new tab on right click as it is not a link.

Comment: @AkashSharma Updated the answer to make the whole cell clickable.

Comment: It is still not covering the whole cell after the addition of this css. You can refer to this image: https://picresize.com/images/tscreenshot_from_2020-06-28_13-19-16.png?868821. The green area is whole cell and blue area is anchor tag.